# JQuery parseJSON and populate a second selection box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

What i would like to happen is when i select an item from the first selection box, the 2nd selection box populates from a parseJSON.

I have 2 selection boxes: #web and #cats

web: has (at the moment) 3 options - All Websites (value=0), Website 1 (value=1) and Website 2 (value=2)

When i select from #web i should only get the categories for that particular website, however in PHP i have already considered "All Websites" and it duplicates the categories into each web object, but i also added "All Websites" to the json array, so that if it is reselected the selection box will repopulate.

This is the PHP Function (To create the JSON):

```
function catWebMix($user) {
    $categories = getCategories($user);
    $webAll = array('ID'=>0, 'WebID'=>'All', 'WebName'=>'All Websites');    
    $webSites = getWebsites($user);
    array_unshift($webSites,$webAll);
    $output = array();
    foreach ($webSites as $k => $v) {
        $output[$k] = $v;
        foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {
            if ($value['WebID'] == '0') {
                $value['WebID'] = $v['ID']; 
                $output[$k]['Category'][] = $value;     
            } else if ($value['WebID'] == $v['ID']) {
                $output[$k]['Category'][] = $value;
            } 
        }
    }
    return array($output, json_encode($output));
    exit;
}
```

I assign a variable to Smarty.

```
$webCats = catWebMix($user);
$smarty->assign('webCats', $webCats);
```

I then call it in JQuery. This is my *failed* attempt at creating the selection boxes change, im unsure on how to do it.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var obj = $.parseJSON({$webCats[1]});
        $('#web').on('change', function () {
            var web = $(this).val();
            $.each(obj, function () {
                if (web == obj.ID) {
                    $.each(obj.Category, function (i,v) {
                        $('#cats').append("<option>"+v[3]+"</option>");
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

What i want it to do:

- Remove all option attributes in #cats
- Repopulate #cats with the data from the parseJson, based on the value from #web. #web value = (first) ID in JSON.
- Place Category.ID as value for option, and Category.CatTitle as text

The json array looks like the following:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 0,
    "WebID": "All",
    "WebName": "All Websites",
    "Category": [
      {
        "ID": "1",
        "WebID": 0,
        "CatTitle": "Category 1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "WebID": "web1",
    "WebName": "Website 1",
    "Category": [
      {
        "ID": "1",
        "WebID": "1",
        "CatTitle": "Category 1"
      },
      {
        "ID": "2",
        "WebID": "1",
        "CatTitle": "Category 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "WebID": "web2",
    "WebName": "Website 2",
    "Category": [
      {
        "ID": "1",
        "WebID": "2",
        "CatTitle": "Category 1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I did it! This was the code i used in case others have issues.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var webCats = {$webCats[1]};
    $('#web').on('change', function () {
        var web = $(this).val();
        $.each(webCats, function (k, o) {
            if (web == o.ID) {
                $('#cats option').remove();
                $.each(o.Category, function (i, v) {
                    $('#cats').append("<option value=\""+v.ID+"\">"+v.CatTitle+"</option>");
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```